# Upload files automatically to an input file from a path

Tags: php, jquery, file, email

I got a DDBB with some paths from different files that I keep in a table. What I'm trying to do is the following:

You can click a button which gets all that paths and loads all the files to an input file just to send it as attached file via e-mail using a php script.

The thing is, I don't know if it is really necessary to take that step with jquery or is it possible to send it straight away using php?

Comment: your question is unclear, but unless the user needs to do something with the data there is not reason to send it back to them first. please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have file paths in DB, which is Backend, and when you create page view you are getting paths from DB by PHP still Backend, then you will put a hidden field etc. when a person click a button 'Frontend but dummy action' you want to load these files and send to backend again.

**Logically;**

If Client and Server are not discrete then this wouldn't be a reliable system, because you are not sure files are in the correct path which means will not be renamed, deleted.

If client and server are the same you don't need to make this with a file upload you already know you have the paths when user click the button ex : button submits the form with id/group_id 1, fetch paths by id or group_id and send by email.

But still you want to do something like that, Html5 has an api http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp for it, beyond that you need to execute an applet to achieve this I think.

Comment: Not to backend again, from backend to attach in an email.